# pic16f877a uart embedded c code

Tags: c, embedded, pic, microchip

I have written code for UART code for PIC16F877A. The code is not working and it's showing an error like pointer required at MP LAB IDE.I want send and receive the characters to PC hyper terminal.

```
#include<pic.h>

void pic_init(void)
{
   TRISC7=1;
   TRISC6=0;
}

void uart_init(void)
{
   TXSTA=0x20;
   RCSTA=0x90;
   SPBRG=15;
}

void tx(unsigned char byte)
{
   int i;
   TXREG=byte;
   while(!TXIF);
   for(i=0;i<400;i++);
}

void string_uart(char *q)
{
   while(*q)
   {
      *(*q++);
   }
}

unsigned char rx()
{
   while(!RCIF);
   return RCREG;
}

void main()
{
   char *q;
   pic_init();
   uart_init();
   tx('N');
   rx();
   string_uart("test program");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this guide](https://electrosome.com/uart-pic-microcontroller-mplab-xc8/). At least you must set the baud rate to do what you want to do. A little tip. Try to short-cutting TX and RX pin and start to make it working. To connect it to PC you also need, at least, a usb to TTL UART (5V) cable.

Comment: If your compiler emits a diagnostic message, you should include the exact message in the question, and indicate exactly which line the message was emitted on.

Comment: @LPs: PCs with legacy serial ports are still available. Although a 232 line driver will then be needed. If his PC has HyperTerminal installed by default, it must be pretty old, and possibly has 232 ports in any case.

Comment: @Clifford What I meant is that OP cannoct connect PIC directly to PC without using, at least, a MAX232. I suggested to use a USB to TTL cable to connect to TX and RX pins directly, maybe on a breadboard test circuit with PIC PDIP package.

Comment: when we set SPBRG value is 15 the buad rate value is 9600 and crystal frequency is 10MhZ as per the datasheet.please reply to me sir.

Comment: could you  suggest to me the forums and tips to learn the embedded system development on quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement within your `while` loop does not make sense:

```
while(*q) {
   *(*q++);
}
```

This results in the `error: (981) pointer required` error you are getting, since you are dereferencing a non-pointer: `*q++` returns a `char`, hence you are trying to dereference a `char` with the outer `*`.

Instead, you probably want to transmit the character to which the pointer currently points (`*q`), and then increment the pointer (`q++`):

```
while(*q) {
    tx(*q);
    q++;
}
```

This could also be written like

```
while(*q) {
    tx(*q++);
}
```

With that, your code **compiles** (with `xc8`), but I have not verified your SFR setup - if the code does not **work**, double check that you have properly setup the SFRs. See the link provided by @LPs for more information: https://electrosome.com/uart-pic-microcontroller-mplab-xc8/

Comment: Thank you.I have compiled the code without error.I will check in proteous and and come back to you sir. –

Answer (score 2):

In the expression:

```
*(*q++) ;
```

You dereference the pointer to get a char, to which you then dereference (`*`) again; but you cannot dereference a non-pointer.

Aside from that, you probably also intended to call `tx()` in `uart_string()` for it to do anything useful.